# Filter with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I want to use jquery to do filter, first I hide all div tags then try to show only selected div tag, I select them in a variable and check the length of the collected div is right but can not loop and show them.

```
 var filter = $('.sec5row.'+classtype); //this is the selected variable
 //I try to loop it and show 
 for (var i = 0; i < = filter.length; i++){
      $(filter[i]).show();
 }


 but then I do filter[1].show() it works
```

Please tell me  the correct way to loop it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all:

```
$('.sec5row.' + classtype).show();
```

[jQuery objects are collections](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/). When you call a method such as [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), it's applied to all elements contained within the object.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to iterate over elements just to show them:

```
 $('.sec5row.'+classtype).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
    $('.sec5row.'+classtype).each(function(this){

//do whatever you want to do in this loop, filtering, display, checking properties etc..$(this) will give you the element selector
$(this).show();

    });
```